# php действие после нажатия кнопку

Tags: php

Не знаю в чем может быть проблема, буду рад любой помощи, знаю что рукожоп.

```
<form method="post">
<input class="rulet_btn" type="submit" name="getskin" value="GET DROP" <?php if($user->balance >= 99){?> onclick="$('#modal7').arcticmodal(); return false;" <?php } else {?> onclick="$('#modal8').arcticmodal(); return false;" <?php  }?> type="submit" style="border:none;"></input>
</form> 
<?php
if($user->balance >= 99){
    if(isset($_POST['getskin'])){
        $tempbal = $user->balance - 99;
        $user->balance = $tempbal;
        R::store($user);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: а рассказываете в чем проблема еще хуже, чем наличие рук в одном месте

Comment: Код после if(isset($_POST['getskin'])) не выполняется при нажатии на данный input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`return false;`** события **`onclick`** вашего **`input type="submit"`** отменяет действие по-умолчанию - отправку данных формы.

Comment: Спасибо большое